# Convert IGrouping from one class to another using linq

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have two classes Teams and PlayerTeams

```
public class PlayerTeams
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public string PlayerCountry { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public string PlayerTeam { get; set; }
}

public class Players
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public bool? Status { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of `PlayerTeams` which is grouped by `PlayerTeam` like this.

```
var groupedPlayers = teams
            .OrderBy(x => x.PlayerName)
            .GroupBy( x => x.PlayerTeam)
            .ToList();
```

Its of type `List<IGrouping<string, PlayerTeams>>` but I want it to be of type `List<IGrouping<string, Players>>` as I do not want the redundant key information on every row.

How could I possibly achieve that? I could only think of something like `.ConvertAll()` on the `IGrouping`. I am not able to make it also.

Is there an efiicient way to do this?

Comment: Your `PlayerTeams` class looks odd to me - isn't it just a composition of `Player` and the team name? Why do you have separate properties?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I am doing modifications on an application already built. This is an abstraction of the problem and the two classes I have have different prop names indeed. One is a Linq2SQL class and another is a mapper class created earlier.

Comment: Okay - it's worth mentioning that sort of thing when you ask the question; if there's anything which looks unusual, it's a good idea to explain it. Additionally, do you *have* to use the existing grouping, or could you just change the code which does the grouping to start with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change the grouping, I'd just use:

```
var groupedPlayers = teams
            .OrderBy(x => x.PlayerName)
            .GroupBy(x => x.PlayerTeam, Players.FromPlayerTeam)
            .ToList();
```

Where `Players.FromPlayerTeam` is a static method in `Players` which takes a `PlayerTeam` and returns a `Players`.

Additionally, I'd suggest using `ToLookup` instead of `GroupBy` - a `Lookup` is exactly what you want here, without bothering with the `ToList` call.

Comment: Ok. I will try with lookup. The same way applies for lookup to convert the data?

Comment: @naveen: Yes - you can specify one projection for the key, and one for the element.

Comment: got it. lookup is pretty fast for this. (This)[http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/31/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-18-tolookup.aspx] also helped me. double thanks.

Comment: @JonSkeet I cannot get why I need the static method. Can you help me?

Comment: @Revious: That's just a method group conversion. You could use a lambda expression if you want, e.g. `GroupBy(x => x.PlayerTeam, team => new Players(...))`

Answer (score 0):

**This not testet, just an idea.**

If you have trouble converting your linq statement, which is expecting the `IGrouping` type, to a string list, then you might have to **select** it before.

```
var groupedPlayers = new List<string>();
groupedPlayers = teams
        .OrderBy(x => x.PlayerName)
        .GroupBy(x => x.PlayerTeam, Players.FromPlayerTeam)
        .Select(x => x.Key) // << added select
        .ToList();
```